# monitor viewmodel property change from another viewmodel using reactiveui

Tags: c#, mvvm, viewmodel, reactiveui

I've been trying to wrap my head around how to use reactiveui to monitor viewmodel properties from a specific instance of a viewmodel.

For example I have a **LoginView** and a **LoginViewModel** I'm able to monitor changes in LoginViewModel by binding LoginView to LoginViewModel which works as expected.

My problem is with my **MainViewModel** I'm not able to access **LoginViewModel** instance properties to monitor changes specifically (AuthToken). What I'm trying to accomplish is the **user clicks a button gets a response from the server when the response is received I would like to perform some action within my MainViewModel based on the loginViewModel property value.**

LoginView

```
public partial class LoginView : ReactiveUserControl<LoginViewModel>
{
    public LoginView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        {
            this.WhenActivated(disposables =>
            {
                this.Bind(this.ViewModel, x => x.EMAIL, x => x.Email_TextBox.Text)
                .DisposeWith(disposables);
                this.Bind(this.ViewModel, x => x.ErrorPlaceHolder, x => x.Error.Content)
                .DisposeWith(disposables);
                this.BindCommand(ViewModel, x => x.LoginCommand, x => x.LoginButton)
                    .DisposeWith(disposables);
                this
                    .passwordBox
                    .Events()
                    .PasswordChanged
                    .Select(_ => this.passwordBox.Password)
                    .Subscribe(x => this.ViewModel.PASSWORD = x)
                    .DisposeWith(disposables);



            });
        }
    }
}
```

LoginViewModel

```
public class LoginViewModel : ReactiveObject, IRoutableViewModel
{

    private readonly ReactiveCommand<Unit, Unit> loginCommand;

    public string UrlPathSegment => "login";
    public IScreen HostScreen { get; }

    private string email;
    private string password;
    private string errorplaceholder;
    private string authtoken;
    private FirebaseAuthLink auth { get; set; }



    public LoginViewModel(IScreen screen = null)
    {



        HostScreen = screen ?? Locator.Current.GetService<IScreen>();

        var canExecute = this.WhenAnyValue(
            x => x.EMAIL, x => x.PASSWORD, (EMAIL, PASSWORD) =>
                    !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(EMAIL) &&
                    !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(PASSWORD));


        this.loginCommand = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask(
            async () =>
            {
                ErrorPlaceHolder = "";
                authtoken = await authLogin(EMAIL, PASSWORD);
                Trace.WriteLine(errorplaceholder);
            }, canExecute);

    }




    public ReactiveCommand<Unit, Unit> LoginCommand => this.loginCommand;

    public string EMAIL
    {
        get => this.email;
        set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref this.email, value);
    }

    public string PASSWORD
    {
        get => this.password;
        set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref this.password, value);
    }

    public string ErrorPlaceHolder
    {
        get => this.errorplaceholder;
        set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref this.errorplaceholder, value);
    }

    public string AuthToken
    {
        get => this.authtoken;
        set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref this.authtoken, value);
    }

    public async Task<string> authLogin(string email, string password)
    {
        var authProvider = new FirebaseAuthProvider(new FirebaseConfig("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"));
        try
        {
            auth = await authProvider.SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(email, password);
            var user = authProvider.GetUserAsync(auth);

            Trace.WriteLine(auth.FirebaseToken);
            return "true";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (ex.Message.Contains("Reason: InvalidEmailAddress"))
            {
                ErrorPlaceHolder = "E-Mail address is invalid";
                return ErrorPlaceHolder;
                //       // EmailErrorColour = "Red";

            }
            else if (ex.Message.Contains("Reason: WrongPassword"))
            {
                ErrorPlaceHolder = "E-Mail address or passowrd is incorrect!";
                return ErrorPlaceHolder;

            }
            else if (ex.Message.Contains("Reason: UserDisabled"))
            {
                ErrorPlaceHolder = "Account is disabled";
                return ErrorPlaceHolder;

            }
            else if (ex.Message.Contains("Reason: MissingPassword"))
            {
                ErrorPlaceHolder = "Missing Password";
                return ErrorPlaceHolder;
            }
            else if (ex.Message.Contains("Reason: UnknownEmailAddress"))
            {
                ErrorPlaceHolder = "E-Mail address not found";
                return ErrorPlaceHolder;
            }
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                ErrorPlaceHolder = "Please contact the IT Department";
                return ErrorPlaceHolder;

            }
        }
    }


}
```

Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: Hi! And welcome to stackoverflow! Would you mind [adding a little more context](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to your question? Could you give us a small sample of code you've been trying?

Comment: I guess what I'm really asking is how do I bind one view aka my mainview to multiple viewmodels.